# Creating Magento-attributes using Magento-Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, extensions, extension-attributes

Need help to create `Magento attributes` using `Magento Extension`. 
Here are the instructions:

I have to create a new `Yes/No` attribute for products. The code should be display_product.

The code should be able to install in `Magento extension` because I will use git and host the code in github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new module using silk software and check need Installing sql or php code and download the zip. After download open the sql file and paste the below code according with your modifications

```
<?php
/** @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'my_custom_attribute',
    array(
        'group' => 'General Information',
        'input' => 'select',
        'type' => 'int',
        'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
        'required' => 0,
        'unique' => 0,
        'sort_order' => 3,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Hello. is there other way to use this code like pasting the code in .phtml. If i am going to paste this code in sql file. Do I have to manually import this file in the phpadmin/mysql?

Comment: no you have to use this code in .sql files then it will magento will run this script

Comment: I use the silk software and use the Need to Add Category Attribute: Yes

Comment: ok copy the above code and paste in that field

Comment: Ok I will be back after 12 hours. I have more question like what if the module is already installed or created?

Comment: I also have other questions. I am having problem in making my website.

Right now I am making a website with the help of creating codes from magento extension and put all codes and files in git and GitHub.

I want to make a website that display chosen products in a new frontend page accessed from the My Account section.

But first I have to create an attribute with name display_product from Magento extension
When the products is set to Yes using attribute display_product, the displayed product is added to the MyAccount Menu Page.

Comment: I also have to add a customize configuration into the System Configuration to modify the limit number of products displayed on the MyAccount page.